# In vtiger crm how can we show and hide " Convert Leads" link in Leads module

Tags: vtiger

In vtiger crm how can we show and hide " Convert Leads" link in Leads module , when we select picklist value then show and hide "Convet Leads" link.
can you explain with code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to code to do it.. You can disable that at the profile of the user. Go to profiles > Leads > Disable the convert lead for that user..

In you want to remove the button go to Leads/DetailView.php